# a question about flex preloaders

Tags: apache-flex, preloader

I'm moving to a pure as3 environment into flex and I have a question about preloaders.

For one of my apps in particular when the swf loaded I would add a screen with an animated preloader. Then at a particular point in my code when I know all of my xml has been parsed, UI built and all initiliztion done I dispatch a "done" event which removes the preloader.

How can I achieve this is flex? I've only ever really seen flex preloaders that are percentage based which I believe represent the actual loading of the swf itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the flex cookbook for preloaders, they have some demo applications, that could help u out

actually there is a preloader property in the application tag,

that could be wht u might help u out
tc

Ankur Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Flex has a [ProgressBar](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html) control that you can use for similar purposes. If you want to continue to use your own custom animated progress bar, you can add that `Sprite` to the `rawChildren` of a Container (preferably `Canvas`) and show it as a modal pop-up using the `PopUpManager` - remove the pop-up from the `done` event's handler.

The overriden `addChild` method of the `Container` class will throw an error if you pass a child that doesn't extend `UIComponent` - that's why you should use `rawChildren.addChild`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep default flex preloader represents the loading of the swf itself.

If I were you, I would use the [Task](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm+Libraries#CairngormLibraries-Task) library from the Cairngorm 3 Libs, works perfectly with a preloader :

http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/cairngorm3/trunk/libraries/TaskTest/src/samples/TaskFlowPreloader.as